# How do you find the list of all the supported HTTP methods by a webserver?

Tags: http, networking, netcat

I've a apache server running on 10.0.0.3, using nc how can i get the list of supported http methods?
I tried with this.. no success.

```
nc 10.0.0.3 80
OPTIONS /
```

and the response is 500 server error..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at
 webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.1.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

What's the mistake in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `curl` using `-i` to show the response headers, and using `-L` to follow any redirects:

```
curl -i -L -X OPTIONS http://10.0.0.3/
```

You’ll see some response headers that include an `Allow` header; example:

```
Allow: OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST
```

If you really want to instead use `nc`, you can do it like this:

```
$ nc 10.0.0.3 80
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.0.3
```

What’s different about that from the `nc` invocation in the question is:

- Append `HTTP/1.1` to the `OPTIONS` line (just as you must with `GET`, `HEAD`, etc.)
- Include a `Host: <hostname>` line after the `OPTIONS` line